# PHP handling analytics snapshots

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a site which will collect data every day/based on interval.

For example:

Day 1 snapshot:

```
{
    [
        'user': 'player1', 
        'points': 354
    ],
    [
        'user': 'player2', 
        'points': 12443
    ],
}
```

Day 2 snapshot:

```
{
    [
        'user': 'player1', 
        'points': 1476
    ],
    [
        'user': 'player2', 
        'points': 14562
    ],
}
```

Day 3 snapshot:

```
{
    [
        'user': 'player1', 
        'points': 3546
    ],
    [
        'user': 'player3', 
        'points': 123
    ],
}
```

How do I keep this this data in MySQL database and how can I manipulate them? Like report from date "x" to date "y". How many points earned between date/today/range. which player joined/left the list at which date. Who is the earner of the day/range date.

Note that there is more fields. Points is just an example. There can be points, xp, wins, losses, etc.

*It's actually clan's stats (game clan). There is no API for it. I'm just having those snapshots*

"Suggest me a good title"

Comment: Have you tried anything you self, then show us please.

Comment: i'm not familier about how to handle this. so i could not do anything :/ i have no idea how to handle it

Comment: i need a good article on this thing.

Comment: There are a few obvious approaches on how to implement the data model. But there is no "best" or something like that. Your choice depends on the way you want to use the data afterwards which we don't know.

Comment: http://www.media-division.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/ follow this

Comment: actually i have no idea. so any good method will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Follow this, you have to learn from it and then apply in your system :

http://www.media-division.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/

Comment: it's gaming stats. stats of game clan. where players enter the clan/leave the clan. as they play they earn points for clan. but when they leave the clan. the clan/player losses the point

Comment: but you need to play around it, this is just a tutorial not your answer Man. :)